# how to use getResources().getXml

Tags: android

I'm trying to use getResources().getXml so that I can access an XML file in my 'res' folder.  Apparently from what I've read, I need something like this:

```
XmlPullParser xpp = context.getResources().getXml(R.xml.encounters);
```

So I put that in, and I also imported "android.content.Context"

But I keep getting an error on 'context' that says:***Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field context***

Is there a way to fix this?

Here is my whole code:

```
package t.HelloAndroid;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;
import android.content.res.XmlResourceParser;
import android.content.Context;
import android.app.Activity;

public class XmlParser  {

public static void main (String args[])
    throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
{

    XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    //XmlResourceParser xrp = context.getResources().getXml(R.xml.encounters);
    XmlPullParser xpp = context.getResources().getXml(R.xml.encounters);

    int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
     if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
         System.out.println("Start document");
     } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
         System.out.println("Start tag "+xpp.getName());
     } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
         System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
     } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
         System.out.println("Text "+xpp.getText());
     }
     eventType = xpp.next();
    }
    System.out.println("End document");
}
}
```

Comment: I have this: public class XmlParser  {
 private Context context;
 public static void main (String args[])
  throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
    {

        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        //XmlResourceParser xrp = context.getResources().getXml(R.xml.encounters);
        XmlPullParser xpp = context.getResources().getXml(R.xml.encounters);

Comment: sorry that formatting looks horrible

Comment: You could edit your original post to put the code in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted will not work, as the `context` is only available within an Activity (or similar) within an Android app. Just calling it via `main()` will not set the correct context for you (in the above example it is even `null` and would result in a NPE).

Answer (score 2):

use your Activity name at place of context .

Answer (score 1):

Make sure this statement is inside a non static method.