# Parse an android XML layout file using XmlPullParser

Tags: android

This question has been asked a lot in different situations, but for over a day I can't find an answer that fixes my error.

I have an xml file called `activity_single_touch.xml` inside `res/layout` folder.
This file is used to add views like buttons, but I also want to be able to edit it "live" (the user can draw on screen).

Following android guide, I tried using `XmlPullParser` in my main java code like so:

```
public class SingleTouchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_touch);
        XmlPullParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.xml.activity_single_touch);
        AttributeSet attributes = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);
        setContentView(new SingleTouchEventView(this, attributes));
    }

    public class SingleTouchEventView extends View {
        ...
    }
}
```

The rest of the code uses `OnDraw` and `OnTouchEvent` to draw a path according to user movement, and then invalidate.

The error I am getting at the moment is "cannot resolve symbol 'xml'".
How can I fix this?

p.s:
Things I have tried (and have failed):
Using

```
XmlPullParser parser =getResources().getXml(R.layout.activity_single_touch);
```

and getting "expected xml element" error,

I've read over

[this guide](http://www.edumobile.org/android/search-interface/)
 [these answeres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36541226/how-to-use-your-own-xml-resource-in-android/36541601#36541601)
[these as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21123811/android-xml-cannot-be-resolved-or-is-not-in-the-field/21124121#21124121)
 [use of streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996136/passing-xml-resource-to-xmlreader/10996202#10996202)
 [use of context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579138/how-to-use-getresources-getxml/8579533)
 [moving the xml file to a different folder(could not move it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634611/how-to-get-xml-from-local-res-raw-folder)
[this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28373487/getting-started-with-xmlpullparser)

and of course searching google and some more stackOverflow questions and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getLayout` method to open the layout file and parse it. This is how you can parse it manually.

Try this,

```
try {
    XmlResourceParser parser = getResources().getLayout(R.layout.activity_single_touch);
    int event = parser.getEventType();
    do{
        String tagName = parser.getName();
        if(event == XmlPullParser.START_TAG){
            Log.e("TagName", tagName);
        }
        event = parser.next();
    } while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT);
} catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Usage in your code,

```
public class SingleTouchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try {
            XmlResourceParser parser = getResources().getLayout(R.layout.activity_single_touch);
            AttributeSet attributes = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);
            setContentView(new SingleTouchEventView(this, attributes));
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class SingleTouchEventView extends View {

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you want me to use this -
I tried changing this line:
XmlPullParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.xml.activity_single_touch);
to the block of code you gave me and it didn't work.
I also tried switching this line to:
XmlResourceParser parser = getResources().getLayout(R.layout.activity_single_touch);
and it didn't work.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? Is the `TagName` not being printed?

Comment: First of all - it tells me on this line:
 AttributeSet attributes = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);
"cannot resolve symbol 'parser'". I thought it's a problem with the scope, so I changed the first few lines of your code to:
 XmlResourceParser parser ;
        try {
             parser = getResources().getLayout(R.layout.activity_main);
...
But then it says "variable 'parser' might not have been initialized".
What else should I do?

Btw - just to make sure I'm using this code in the right place, this is all in the OnCreate method instead of the line quoted in the above comment.

Comment: I do in my code, and I asked few times if you mean that I just change that one line of my code into this block you gave me and keep the rest, otherwise I don't know how to use this block.
Otherwise how do I use this parser? How do I implement it so that the ui includes both the SingleTouchEventView  from the java file, and different views from the xml file?

Comment: compiled with no errors, but I can't see the button from my xml view.. only a blank screen I can draw on (SingleTouchEventView).

Maybe I need to add something to the xml code? I'll add the first few lines to my question

Comment: It's not letting me. I'll try here:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.paint.MainActivity">